# concept : best practice for constructing fields in multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, appcelerator

i have a number of bus routes of which the stops are on multiple bus routes

what would be the best way of laying out the tables

at the moment i have table 1 (sqlite db on iphone)

```
unique id | line_no | direction | etc
```

table 2 (online mysql)

```
unique id | parent_id (= unique id from table1) | lat | lng | line_no |
```

instead of having multiple entries with the same lat & lng for each different line i need to obviously have 2 extra column fields for each single stop that contains a reference to parents and also line no

in the map showing the points for each line then its not an issue since the query just pulls the stops based on the parent id but when i do a "nearest" stop query if a stop has more than 1 route i get multiple markers

so for example on stop a in table2 (online mysql) i would need

```
unique id | parent_id      | line_no    | lat    | lng

1         | 6, 12, 16, 19, | 2, 4, 7,10 | 55.111 | 12.444
```

etc

so basically how would i build the query so that when i query based on lat & lng the json i get back can be used to build eg a tableview  & display 6 with 2, 12 with 4 etc, split the pairings so i can do a subsequent link on each?

(i'm doing this in appcelerator - table1 is an sqlite db on the iphone, the lat/lng query on table 2 is on a mysql database from php that creates a json array)

if this makes any sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a *very* good reason to do something different, the [rules of relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) normalization define how to structure your database.

In your case you just need a third table to decompose the n:m relationship between table 1 (bus_routes) and table 2 (bus_stops) instead of multiple records in bus_stops for each combination of bus_stop and bus_route.

And your current structure is wrong - if a a record in bus_routes is uniquely defined by the line_no and direction, then why do you have a surrogate key as well?

> but when i do a "nearest" stop query if a stop has more than 1 route i get multiple markers

Where's your SQL?

> table1 is an sqlite db on the iphone, the lat/lng query on table 2 is on a mysql database

What use is 'table 1' without 'table 2'?

Comment: table 1 is the table used to build up a list of available routes - there is another seperate sqlite table which has all the timetable information for each of the routes (separate but just fyi)  the only time table 2 is used is when constructing the map points - since a user would have to be online anyway i use an online mysql db

Comment: the query for "nearest": $query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM `lines` WHERE type='1' HAVING distance < '%s'  ORDER BY distance ".$limit_sql,
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));